# Segue identifier not showing in attributes inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I go to click on the segue in my storyboard and nothing shows up in the attributes inspector.. why would this be? All I ask for is to identify this segue in code. Can someone help me? I have x-code version 5.1.1.

[image]

EDIT: OSX Version : 10.8.5

Comment: Try selecting something else and come select again the segue.

Comment: tried that, no-dice. I'm thinking since I don't have mavericks, maybe this is a new and upcoming bug.

Comment: On accident, I updated X-code. The older version I had before worked just fine.

Comment: Ok. Because sometimes, I get also this issue. It seems that its when the App/GraphicObjectSelection loses focus, and when I go back, it forget half that it was selected (the item is shown selected, but the inspector panel show "nothing" like yours).

Comment: What two things are you connecting to? Like for example, navigation controller to tableViewController. @user3124081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a show/hide button next to "Storyboard segue", conveniently someone thought it was good UX to hide it, so just hover your mouse near that area and your will see it.
[image]

Comment: Wow, you are a life-saver. I can't believe how hard that was to find. UX dept. needs to revisit a Steve Jobs 101 class.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i managed to solve the issue (Solution for “NO SELECTION”) for XCode 7.2 as follow :

- Select another file (which isn’t an Interface Builder type) in the
  current tab with the issue.
- Open a new tab and select the Interface Builder file which was having
  the problem.